# Cargo una imagen a android studio para usarla como background y no me ocupa el total de la vista, se muestra con forma ovalada

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview, image-view, emulador

mi problema radica en que necesito cargar una imagen a la app que estoy creando para usarlar en una de las vistas como background de la misma, el problema es que cuando lo cargo, no se me guarda en la carpeta drawable, sino que se me guarda dentro de la carpeta mipmap. Teniendo en cuenta eso, probe de  distintas formas para poder cargarla y visializarla, usando un FrameLayout y dentro de este un ImageView(con sus scaleType en centerCrop para no perder la calidad de las dimensiones) para que quede la imagen de fondo y los demás componentes arriba, y no me funciono.
Probe poniendoselo en un linerLayout como su android:bakcground, tampoco me funciono. y por último ahora estoy probando con un RelativeLayout, pero tampoco.

El problema es que en ninguno de los casos, la imagen de fondo toma el area completa de la pantalla del emulador del dispositivo en el que necesito usarlo, sino más bien toma una forma ovalada. No entiendo porque me hace ese efecto. Y cada vez que lo intento cargar a la carpeta drawable, directamente se crea en el mipmap.

El tamaño de la imagen es de 1900x1080, y uso como dispositivo emular una tablet.

En la siguiente imagen, las carpetas "ic_menu_init", es la imagen que se debio guardar en drawable y que se guardo en mipmap

[image: En la siguiente imagen, las carpetas "ic_menu_init", es la imagen que se debio guardar en drawable y que se guardo en mipmap]

Este el último código que intente utilizar para que la imagen ocupe toda la pantalla:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_menu_init"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ya no se que más probar ni porque reacciona asi el componente, la app o la img.

**SOLUCION**

Encontre la raiz del problema, primero antes que nada, gracias mateo por tu colaboración, tu respuesta fue la más acertada y me ayudo muchisimo a llegar al resultado, el problema de que la imagen no se cargara bien era porque iniciaba con un número, luego el tema de como lo cargaba no era correcto, ya que la imagen que quisiera agregar al drawable bastaba con arrastrarla a la carpeta misma. pude lograr que la iamgen abarque toda la pantalla sin perder resolución ni se deformara. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Los **mipmaps** también son **drawables**. La característica particular de estos es que al ser una imagen hecha de píxeles, se carga una resolución diferente en cada dispositivo para que se vea mejor. Los **mipmaps** se utilizan en juegos también. Puedes averiguar más al respecto buscando en internet.

Comment: Entiendo @Mateo sin embargo, siendo que tamb son drawables, no entiendo porque no me funciona correctamente el componente con las iamgenes

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es de la imagen ni su formato.

La imagen se establece como fondo de un [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout), cuyas dimensiones se ajustan para coincidir con las del padre:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Por ese motivo la imagen se estira. Si le dieras las dimensiones adecuadas se vería bien.

Lo mejor para mostrar imágenes son los [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView). Para establecer la imagen que quieres mostrar puedes usar la propiedad `src`. Para cambiar como se muestra la imagen, juega con la propiedad [`scaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:scaleType).

El código se  vería así:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_init"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Aquí tienes un par de enlaces relacionados:

- [Android ImageView ScaleType: A Visual Guide](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)
- [How to align ImageView to the bottom, fill its width and height, and keep its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20325367/13419694)
- [Android Background image fit screen without stretching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28847652/13419694)

Comment: ahi subi una respuesta de como me quedo la imagen aplixando tu código, y también añadi más detalle de como la fui cargando a las imagenes si sirve de orientación

Comment: No entiendo qué tiene mal mí respuesta que me votaron negativo xd

Comment: no vi que tuviera voto negativo, sacando el mio que subi como para añadir más detalle jaja

Comment: @TatianaDelsoglio si tocas el número de la puntuación puedes ver todos los votos negativos y positivos